# Getting connection timed out while installing Jenkins plugins through Dockerfile

Tags: jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to install Jenkins 2.393 version through Dockerfile, I am getting an timed out error while trying to download Plugins. Can someone help me out? Please find the below Dockerfile and Attached error what I am getting.
Error I am getting:

```
Unable to resolve plugin URL https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/ansicolor/1.0.2/ansicolor.hpi, or download plugin ansicolor to file: Connect to ftp-chi.osuosl.org:443 [ftp-chi.osuosl.org/64.50.236.52] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
Tried downloading ansicolor from https://ftp-chi.osuosl.org/pub/jenkins/plugins/ansicolor/1.0.2/ansicolor.hpi (attempt 1 of 3)
```